# Ran More Than 40 Minutes Past 7pm

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage, paraphrasing

I have a question about some usage involving the verb "*run*" in this [new article](http://www.nytimes.com/1996/10/02/arts/shrinking-dateline.html):

> ...NBC's coverage of a San Diego-Kansas City football game ***ran more than 40 minutes past 7 P.M***...

I am not too sure what "*ran more than 40 minutes past 7 p.m.*" mean.  Would the following, depending on the intended meaning:

> 1. NBC's coverage of a San Diego-Kansas City football game *ran* ***until*** *more than 40 minutes past 7 P.M.*
> 2. NBC's coverage of a San Diego-Kansas City football game *ran* ***for a period of time ending*** *after more than 40 minutes past 7 P.M*.

be better rewrites?

Answer (score 1):

Coverage of an American football game may "run over", that is, it may encroach upon a show scheduled for a particular time, if the game lasts longer than anticipated.

If the coverage ran more than 40 minutes past 7PM, it ran to at least 7:40.  Whether it ran only a few seconds or a few minutes past is not clear. But most likely it was fewer than 45 minutes longer.

Your suggested rewrites are not better than the original because the idiomatic locution follows this pattern:

X  "ran" { number {time units} } "past|over" {the starting time of another show}

That is, it expresses how far the coverage *extended into* the show regularly scheduled, how much the coverage encroached upon that show.